# Redis installed but not loading in WAMP

Tags: php, redis, wamp

ERROR LOG:

`[09-Mar-2020 18:50:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'redis' (tried: c:/Wamp/bin/php/php7.2.4/ext/redis (The specified module could not be found.), c:/Wamp/bin/php/php7.2.4/ext/php_redis.dll (The specified procedure could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0`

I installed the php_reddis.dll in my c:/Wamp/bin/php/php7.2.4/ext/ folder on Windows 10. When I start WAMP I get this the afore mentioned error. Is there a library I was supposed to install that I didn't see?

[image: redis file location]

Comment: Did you check that it is being loaded in your `php.ini` file? https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php

Comment: Its is loaded like this in the php.ini. Wouldn't it need to be trying to load from the php.ini to return an error?

```;extension=phpdbg_webhelper
extension=redis
;extension=shmop```

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the below steps carefully.

Step 1. Print `phpinfo()`

Step 2. Check PHP version (e.g. PHP Version 7.4.0) and visit https://pecl.php.net/package/redis site and according to your PHP version, select the package.
e.g. For PHP 7.4, https://pecl.php.net/package/redis/5.2.2/windows

Step 3. In `phpinfo(),` search `Thread Safety` check whether it's `enabled` or `disabled`. If enabled you need to download Thread Safe (`TS`). Otherwise, download Non Thread Safe (`NTS`)

Step 4. Now extract the zip and get `php_redis.dll` and paste it to php extension folder in Wamp Server(`wamp64\bin\php\php7.x.x\ext\`)

Step 5. Add the `extension=php_redis.dll` in your `php.ini` (By clicking on Wamp->PHP->php.ini)

Step 6. Restart the WAMP server and search `redis` in `phpinfo()`.